# Read CSV into array to sort numerically by numbers given in the lines

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, fault

I try to read a temporary file consisting of several lines like the following example. The lines are NOT sorted.

```
3;NOK
2;OK
1;NA
```

For an easy output-function, in which I want to offer several possibilities of output (CSV, Print on Screen...), I thought it would be clever to do the following.

1. Open the file
2. Iterate through the lines
3. Extract the number at the beginning
4. Use this as index of an array
5. The result should be a "sorted" array

A minimal example which gives me an Segmentation Fault.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
FILE *outfp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if (outfp == NULL){
 printf("There was a problem: Temporary output-file could not be opened");
 return 1;
}
// OUTPUT HANDLING
char output_line[1024];
char output_cut[1024];
int line_number;
char *output_array[3];  //The maximum number of possible entries is fixed

// I got variables for the line, for the linenumber and output_cut is needed for sscanf
while(fgets(output_line, sizeof(output_line), outfp)!=NULL){
 sscanf(output_line,"%d;%s",&line_number,output_cut);
 output_array[line_number]=output_line;
}
printf("LINE1:%s",output_array[1]);
printf("LINE2:%s",output_array[2]);
printf("LINE3:%s",output_array[3]);
return 0;
}
```

My first question: Is this the right way to do, or are there other better ways to "sort" this kind of file in an easy way for flexible output?
If yes, why does this not work?

Regards
Markus

Edit: the example textfile just contains numbers from 1-3... not 13,14...

Edit2: the solution

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
FILE *outfp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if (outfp == NULL){
 printf("There was a problem: Temporary output-file could not be opened");
 return 1;
}
// OUTPUT HANDLING
char output_line[1024];
char output_cut[1024];
int line_number;
char output_array[4][1024];     //The maximum number of possible entries is fixed

// I got variables for the line, for the linenumber and output_cut is needed for sscanf
while(fgets(output_line, sizeof(output_line), outfp)!=NULL){
 sscanf(output_line,"%d;%s",&line_number,output_cut);
 strcpy(output_array[line_number],output_line);
}
printf("LINE1: %s",output_array[1]);
printf("LINE2: %s",output_array[2]);
printf("LINE3: %s",output_array[3]);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two major problems with the code as shown in the question. The first is that all the pointers in the `output_array` points to the same place. This means that when you print the lines all will print the same (which will be the last line read).

The second problem is your array indexing. Array indices goes from zero to the size minus one, so for your `output_array` the indices are `0` to `2` (inclusive). The problem causing the crash is that you use index `3` which is out of bound for the array, and leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I got the second problem and must say, that I didn't do the mistake in the main code.
But how can I solve the first problem?

Comment: @Markus The first problem can be solved in a couple of ways. The simplest is to use a function such as `strdup` to "duplicate" the string. The backside is that the function allocates new memory for the duplicate that you have to `free` later. The second is to make `output_array` an array of arrays (e.g. `char output_array[3][1024]`) and use `strcpy` to copy the string.

Comment: Ok, that was the solution. Because I can not "Answer" my own question I will edit the solution into the topic.

Comment: @Markus I found another couple of problems: You do not initialize the local variable `line_number`, so it will have an indeterminate value and using it without initialization is another case of undefined behavior. You also don't increase it in the reading loop, so all copying will go to the same index in the array.

Comment: The initialization could be done with int line_number=0; 

Increasing is not neccessary, because the line_number is read from the line of the CSV-FILE (%d;%d).

Comment: @Markus Ah I missed that, sorry. Then technically you don't need to initialize it either, as it's initialized by the `sscanf` call.